# Handling PushNotifcations when in a specific viewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, appdelegate

I am trying to handle `PushNotifcation` when my app is in foreground.
If the `ViewController` that is just active is a specific one, I want to reload it's data. If it is inactive, I want my app to instantiate a specific viewController

Here is my code in `appDelegate`:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if userInfo["matchInfo"] != nil {

        if application.applicationState == .active {

            if self.window!.rootViewController is chatUebersichtTVC{
                let uebersicht = self.window!.rootViewController as! chatUebersichtTVC
                uebersicht.refresh()
            }
            else{
            return
            }


        }
        else{
            print ("trying to activate")
            let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let chat:chatUebersichtTVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatUebersichtTVC") as! chatUebersichtTVC
            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chat)
            let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
        }



    }
      else{
               PFPush.handle(userInfo)

     }
             completionHandler(.newData)

 }
```

I am able to get to the line `self.window!.rootViewController is chatUebersichtTVC`
But it doesn't execute afterwards. Also when the app is closed, it will always open the last opened controller, rather than the specific chatUebersichTVC.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest using NotificationCenter in AppDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification (for active state). Add your view controller as observer in  viewWillAppear and remove it in viewDidDisappear. This will make sure you make refresh on the right instance and also will make it easier to refresh any other controllers as well if you need later.

Comment: does your code enter the body of this if statement `if self.window!.rootViewController is chatUebersichtTVC`?

Comment: @alex do you have sample code for this ?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj no it is hanging on this statement. it is not entering it.

Comment: @JVS You should not rely on self.window!.rootViewController type because it can easily be a UINavigationController with your chatUebersichtTVC on the top and the check will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code using NotificationCenter:

First, you have to declare notification name. Prior to Swift 3 we used strings for that, now it should be done as extension for Notification.Name:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let pushNotificationReceived = Notification.Name("pushNotificationReceived")
}
```

Now you can post a notification in your method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {    
    if userInfo["matchInfo"] != nil {
        if application.applicationState == .active {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.pushNotificationReceived, object: nil)
        }
        else{
            //create a new view controller and add it to the hierarchy
        }
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Now any object can listen to this notification and do whatever it needs to. You just need to subscribe and unsubscribe whenever needed. In your case it would be wise to do it in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.refresh), name: Notification.Name.pushNotificationReceived, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.pushNotificationReceived, object: nil)
}

func refresh() {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: so i am just receiving notifications don't I? I don't really need a notification to pop up.

Comment: excuse me just saw the error was from due to my remote setup and due to your code.